# Can <li> be used as a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

`<ul>`serves as a good flexbox container for `<li>`.

However, when I try to use `<li>` as a container for other inline items like `<i>` or `<span>` it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong (example below) or does the `<li>` not make a good flexbox container?

See this example pen in action: http://codepen.io/bobtabor/pen/PWyZBQ

Here is my DESIRED result:

[image: Desired Result]

HOWEVER this is my ACTUAL result:

[image: Actual result]

In this example, I want the font-awesome pencil icon aligned to the right of each `<li>`.  I would expect to define a class with the `align-self: flex-end` property like so:

```
.fa-pencil {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

... to take care of this.  However, when I run this in Chrome or Edge on Windows, the .fa-pencil aligns to the left (the start).

I have simple HTML markup:

```
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <span>Item 1</span>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </li>

    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <span>Item 2</span>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </li>

    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <span>Item 3</span>
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position:inside;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;   
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.fa-bars {
}

.fa-pencil {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

I've been able to confirm that `<li>`'s children are, in fact, responding to Flexbox because I can set the order of `.fa-bars` like so:

```
.fa-bars {
  order: 2;
}
```

... and see the bars icon respond accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.fa-pencil { margin-left: auto; }
```

Your flex container (`li`) has `flex-direction: row`. This means the main axis is horizontal and the cross axis is vertical.

The `align-self` property works only on the cross axis. So the `align-self` on `.fa-pencil` will move the item up/down, not left/right.

Since there is no `justify-self` for the main axis, you can use an `auto` margin to space the pencil icon to the right edge.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEmXvM)

More details here: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties)

Comment: Well, that definitely works!  Thank you.  Thanks for the explanation, the example and the link ... clearly, I did not correctly understand cross vs. horizontal axis.  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `justify-content: space-between;` even better.

Modified code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwwLzO)